# Database Switching in Node Application for each client

Tags: node.js, architecture, node-modules

I have multiple clients on the system and each of the clients will have an individual database. but I don't see any solutions to serve the respective database for the client with each API.

Please guide me to serve API call with client respected database in Node.

Comment: SO is for specific detailed questions only.  You cant ask for something as big and wide ranging as this.

Comment: oh, really... I thought SO is a Platform to get such a Technical solution and its detailed question for me as my technical knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use of [environment variables](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786). You essentially will pass these in to whatever deployment you'll be using, and then you can access them with the `dotenv` package and `process.env`